# How to reduce eth.filter.watch delay?

Tags: go-ethereum, web3js, events, meteor

I have a test contract that emits events. I'd like to create a web app that shows a list of all created events + new ones as they arrive. I'm using Meteor app connected to geth 1.4.10 through rpc. The code is:

```
var filter = web3.eth.filter({fromBlock:0, toBlock: 'latest', address: contract.address, 'topics':[topic]});
filter.watch(function(error, result) {
  // attach event to list
  console.log("Event: " + result);
});
```

It seems to work, however there's a huge (above a minute) delay to get the events that are already created in the callback. I'd like to show a list immediately or almost immediately when the page is loaded and then keep updating as new events come. Is this the correct way? How can I reduce the delay?

Comment: `fromBlock` could probably start at the block at which the contract was deployed.

Comment: @XavierLeprêtreB9lab Thanks! This did a trick it now works immediately.

Comment: Note that this solution isn't perfect-- as time goes on, the process will become slower and slower. Do you need to show *all* previous events? It might make sense to show only events from the last 10,000 blocks, then go back farther upon request. (i.e. a "Show more" button )

Comment: Also, @XavierLeprêtreB9lab you should post this as an answer, since it does fully answer the question.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out @TjadenHess. I was thinking about that too. As more blocks come "Show more" button may be the way to go, but it won't be perfect thought, especially when there'll be a number of blocks without any event (I guess in such case "Show more" may get unresponsive). Another possible solution I can think of is just caching the results, thanks to the blockchain being immutable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`fromBlock` could probably start at the block at which the contract was deployed.